# No output file after running slurm dmtcp job

Tags: slurm, sbatch

After running a SLURM job, I can't find the output file anywhere. The `squeue` command shows that the job is executing correctly, and there aren't any error logs on the current directory, from which I call the `sbatch dmtcp-slurm.job`. Could this be happening because theere's a error which prevents the output file from being created?

dmtcp-slurm.job:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Put your SLURM options here
#SBATCH --time=00:15:00           # put proper time of reservation here
#SBATCH --nodes=2                 # number of nodes
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=4       # processes per node
#SBATCH --mem=1983                # memory resource
#SBATCH --job-name="dmtcp_job"    # change to your job name
#SBATCH --output=dmtcp.out        # change to proper file name or remove for defaults
# ? Any other batch options ?

#----------------------------- Set up DMTCP environment for a job ------------#

###############################################################################
# Start DMTCP coordinator on the launching node. Free TCP port is automatically
# allocated.  This function creates a dmtcp_command.$JOBID script, which serves
# as a wrapper around dmtcp_command.  The script tunes dmtcp_command for the
# exact dmtcp_coordinator (its hostname and port).  Instead of typing
# "dmtcp_command -h <coordinator hostname> -p <coordinator port> <command>",
# you just type "dmtcp_command.$JOBID <command>" and talk to the coordinator
# for JOBID job.
###############################################################################

start_coordinator()
{
    ############################################################
    # For debugging when launching a custom coordinator, uncomment 
    # the following lines and provide the proper host and port for 
    # the coordinator.
    ############################################################
    # export DMTCP_COORD_HOST=$h
    # export DMTCP_COORD_PORT=$p
    # return

    fname=dmtcp_command.$SLURM_JOBID
    h=`hostname`

    check_coordinator=`which dmtcp_coordinator`
    if [ -z "$check_coordinator" ]; then
        echo "No dmtcp_coordinator found. Check your DMTCP installation and PATH settings."
        exit 0
    fi

    dmtcp_coordinator --daemon --exit-on-last -p 0 --port-file $fname $@ 1>/dev/null 2>&1
    
    while true; do 
        if [ -f "$fname" ]; then
            p=`cat $fname`
            if [ -n "$p" ]; then
                # try to communicate ? dmtcp_command -p $p l
                break
            fi
        fi
    done
    
    # Create dmtcp_command wrapper for easy communication with coordinator
    p=`cat $fname`
    chmod +x $fname
    echo "#!/bin/bash" > $fname
    echo >> $fname
    echo "export PATH=$PATH" >> $fname
    echo "export DMTCP_COORD_HOST=$h" >> $fname
    echo "export DMTCP_COORD_PORT=$p" >> $fname
    echo "dmtcp_command \$@" >> $fname

    # Set up local environment for DMTCP
    export DMTCP_COORD_HOST=$h
    export DMTCP_COORD_PORT=$p

}

###################################################################################
# Print out the SLURM job information.  Remove this if you don't need it.
###################################################################################

# Print out the SLURM job information. Remove this if you don't need it.
echo "SLURM_JOBID="$SLURM_JOBID
echo "SLURM_JOB_NODELIST"=$SLURM_JOB_NODELIST
echo "SLURM_NNODES"=$SLURM_NNODES
echo "SLURMTMPDIR="$SLURMTMPDIR
echo "working directory = "$SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR

# changedir to workdir
cd $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR


#----------------------------------- Set up job environment ------------------#

###############################################################################
# Load all nessesary modules or export PATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH/etc here.
# Make sure that the prefix for the DMTCP install path is in PATH
# and LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
###############################################################################

#           **** IF USING Open MPI 1.8, SEE COMMENT BELOW ****
# module load openmpi
###############################################################################
# For Open MPI 1.8, if using InfiniBand, uncomment the following statement
# export OMPI_MCA_mpi_leave_pinned=0
# This could prevent a bug due to interaction with memalign() and ptmalloc2()
# on restart.
###############################################################################

# export PATH=<dmtcp-install-path>/bin:$PATH
# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<dmtcp-install-path>/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

#------------------------------------- Launch application ---------------------#

################################################################################
# 1. Start DMTCP coordinator
################################################################################

start_coordinator # -i 120 ... <put dmtcp coordinator options here>


################################################################################
# 2. Launch application
# 2.1. If you use mpiexec/mpirun to launch an application, use the following
#      command line:
#        $ dmtcp_launch --rm mpiexec <mpi-options> ./<app-binary> <app-options>
# 2.2. If you use PMI1 to launch an application, use the following command line:
#        $ srun dmtcp_launch --rm ./<app-binary> <app-options>
# Note: PMI2 is not supported yet.
# 2.3. If you use the Stampede supercomputer at Texas Advanced Computing Center
#      (TACC), use ibrun command to launch the application (--rm is not required):
#        $ ibrun dmtcp_launch ./<app-binary> <app-options>
################################################################################

dmtcp_launch --rm mpirun -np ./NPB3.4.2/NPB3.4-MPI/bin/lu.C.x
```

slur.conf

```
# slurm.conf file generated by configurator.html.
# Put this file on all nodes of your cluster.
# See the slurm.conf man page for more information.
#
ControlMachine=master
#ControlAddr=
#BackupController=
#BackupAddr=
#
AuthType=auth/munge
#CheckpointType=checkpoint/none
CryptoType=crypto/munge
#DisableRootJobs=NO
#EnforcePartLimits=NO
#Epilog=
#EpilogSlurmctld=
#FirstJobId=1
#MaxJobId=999999
#GresTypes=
#GroupUpdateForce=0
#GroupUpdateTime=600
#JobCheckpointDir=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/checkpoint
#JobCredentialPrivateKey=
#JobCredentialPublicCertificate=
#JobFileAppend=0
#JobRequeue=1
#JobSubmitPlugins=1
#KillOnBadExit=0
#LaunchType=launch/slurm
#Licenses=foo*4,bar
#MailProg=/usr/bin/mail
#MaxJobCount=5000
#MaxStepCount=40000
#MaxTasksPerNode=128
MpiDefault=pmi2
#MpiParams=ports=#-#
#PluginDir=
#PlugStackConfig=
#PrivateData=jobs
ProctrackType=proctrack/linuxproc
#Prolog=
#PrologFlags=
#PrologSlurmctld=
#PropagatePrioProcess=0
#PropagateResourceLimits=
#PropagateResourceLimitsExcept=
#RebootProgram=
ReturnToService=1
#SallocDefaultCommand=
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.pid
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmd.pid
SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmd
SlurmUser=slurm
#SlurmdUser=root
#SrunEpilog=
#SrunProlog=
StateSaveLocation=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmctld
SwitchType=switch/none
#TaskEpilog=
TaskPlugin=task/none
#TaskPluginParam=
#TaskProlog=
#TopologyPlugin=topology/tree
#TmpFS=/tmp
#TrackWCKey=no
#TreeWidth=
#UnkillableStepProgram=
#UsePAM=0
#
#
# TIMERS
#BatchStartTimeout=10
#CompleteWait=0
#EpilogMsgTime=2000
#GetEnvTimeout=2
#HealthCheckInterval=0
#HealthCheckProgram=
InactiveLimit=0
KillWait=30
#MessageTimeout=10
#ResvOverRun=0
MinJobAge=300
#OverTimeLimit=0
SlurmctldTimeout=120
SlurmdTimeout=300
#UnkillableStepTimeout=60
#VSizeFactor=0
Waittime=0
#
#
# SCHEDULING
#DefMemPerCPU=0
FastSchedule=1
#MaxMemPerCPU=0
#SchedulerRootFilter=1
#SchedulerTimeSlice=30
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SchedulerPort=7321
SelectType=select/linear
#SelectTypeParameters=
#
#
# JOB PRIORITY
#PriorityFlags=
#PriorityType=priority/basic
#PriorityDecayHalfLife=
#PriorityCalcPeriod=
#PriorityFavorSmall=
#PriorityMaxAge=
#PriorityUsageResetPeriod=
#PriorityWeightAge=
#PriorityWeightFairshare=
#PriorityWeightJobSize=
#PriorityWeightPartition=
#PriorityWeightQOS=
#
#
# LOGGING AND ACCOUNTING
#AccountingStorageEnforce=0
#AccountingStorageHost=
#AccountingStorageLoc=
#AccountingStoragePass=
#AccountingStoragePort=
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/none
#AccountingStorageUser=
AccountingStoreJobComment=YES
ClusterName=facet-cluster
#DebugFlags=
#JobCompHost=
#JobCompLoc=
#JobCompPass=
#JobCompPort=
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
#JobCompUser=
#JobContainerType=job_container/none
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/none
SlurmctldDebug=3
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=3
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmd.log
#SlurmSchedLogFile=
#SlurmSchedLogLevel=
#
#
# POWER SAVE SUPPORT FOR IDLE NODES (optional)
#SuspendProgram=
#ResumeProgram=
#SuspendTimeout=
#ResumeTimeout=
#ResumeRate=
#SuspendExcNodes=
#SuspendExcParts=
#SuspendRate=
#SuspendTime=
#
#
# COMPUTE NODES
NodeName=node[1-2] CPUs=2 RealMemory=1983 Sockets=1 CoresPerSocket=2 ThreadsPerCore=1 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=all Nodes=node[1-2] Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

Comment: The submit script looks good. Do you have a  filesystem common to all compute and submit nodes?

Comment: @damienfrancois I don't have one. Do you mean something like NFS?

Comment: yes. In that case, the file you are looking for is probably there on the compute node. Until you have a NFS server, you will not see it from the submit node

Comment: @damienfrancois thanks, I was able to find the output.out file on the first node.